# How to reuse HistorySearchDialog.java in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to invoke HistorySearchDialog.java from another location. It’s useful for me to search SVN history with different criteria.

How can I import and use that dialog?

That class present in org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.jar

Please help me with sample example where I can reuse HistorySearchDialog.java and invoke on any action.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in which plug-in this dialog resides, you may view the plugin.xml of the plugin, whether you find the appropriate extension point. I guess you not only want to reuse the dialog, but the functionality. 
To get access to the plug-in you may use the File->Import...->Import Plug-Ins and Fragments and import your target-platform or select the desired plug-ins manually.
Without a public extension point the chances are not too good though.